# How to get Tkinter Python3.x to nest grids?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, grid-layout

I've been trying for days to figure out how to just put grids in grids of objects.  I've got two frames (which I guess are widgets in Tk?) I add one to the other, but the position of *its* widgets don't appear to respect the parent widgets (and it just overwrites them).

here is my MCVE

```
import tkinter as tk
class TestDoubleNested(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.test_label = tk.Label(text="AAAAAAAAA")
        self.test_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

class TestNested(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.test_label = tk.Label(text="top_level_test_label")
        self.test_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.test_label2 = tk.Label(text="top_level_test_label2")
        self.test_label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        # expected to be in 3rd column...
        self.test = TestDoubleNested(master)
        self.test.grid(row=0, column=4)


test = TestNested()
test.master.title("Test Example")
test.master.maxsize(1000, 400)
test.master.wm_geometry("400x300")

test.mainloop()
```

No matter how I move around self.grid() invokations or change the column stuff, the display is the same:

[image: text "AAAAAAAAA" overlapping "top_level_test_label" in a window]

As you can see AAAAAAAA displays *on top of* another widget from the parent, where ideally it should display *to the side* of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't specifying the `master` for each widget, so they are all being added to the root window. If you want widgets to be inside frames, you must specify the frame as the first argument when creating the widgets:

```
class TestDoubleNested(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ...
        self.test_label = tk.Label(self, text="AAAAAAAAA")
        ...


class TestNested(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ...
        self.test_label = tk.Label(self, ...)
        self.test_label2 = tk.Label(self, ...)
        self.test = TestDoubleNested(self)
        ...
```

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure why half the tutorials out there insist on not doing that, I had no idea that's how this worked, I had assumed there was some implicit mechanism orchestrating parents.

Comment: @opa: can you show me a link to a tutorial that says that? I've never seen a tutorial that didn't include specifying the master.